# catch what usb device name is used. vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm creating a VB.Net project for turnstile. My problem is that I need to know that specific usb rfid reader is used so that I can give command to the turnstile what turn is it going to do. For example if the id is tapped at the rfid for entrance it will turn to enter.

I've seen C# code on the internet and tried it to convert to VB.Net, but unfortunately I got lost. It uses RawInputProcessor.dll

C# that I found:

```
protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
    _r = new RawPresentationInput(this, RawInputCaptureMode.Foreground);
    _r.KeyPressed += OnKeyPressed;
    DeviceCount = _r.NumberOfKeyboards;
    base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
}

private void StartWndProcHandler()
{
    _r = new RawPresentationInput(this, RawInputCaptureMode.Foreground);
    _r.KeyPressed += OnKeyPressed;
    DeviceCount = _r.NumberOfKeyboards;
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = PropertyChanged;
    if (propertyChanged != null)
    {
        propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

private void OnKeyPressed(object sender, RawInputEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.IsActive)
    {
        Keyboard.ClearFocus();
        Event = e;
        DeviceCount = _r.NumberOfKeyboards;
        if (Event.Device.Name == Configuration.device1_in && e.KeyPressState == KeyPressState.Up)
        {
            //do stuff for the turnstile
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would be able to help but the only way I know how to work with USB Drives is to detect if they are plugged in or not. I added a vba tag to hopefully get you an answer!

Comment: Thanks @Kyvex I appreciate it.

Comment: @Kyvex I removed the vba tag. VBA is not the same as VB.NET.

Comment: Which bit did you get lost on? The code posted doesn't appear complete.

Comment: protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e) // I dont know what is the equivalent of this code in vb.net
{
    _r = new RawPresentationInput(this, RawInputCaptureMode.Foreground); // when I convert "this" to "Me" I have an error or cannot convert to visual. This is the part that I'm lost. 
    _r.KeyPressed += OnKeyPressed;
    DeviceCount = _r.NumberOfKeyboards;
    base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
}